# Spark remove alias

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have an issue in Spark, where I have a dataframe. This gets passed to some other functions, which does some filtering. I then create a second dataset out of this and join them up. As the first df can have multiple additional columns, which are irrelevant for the filtering part but have to be kept, I select all columns from the first dataframe. This step is done with a right join and I use an alias to be able to reference the columns from the first dataframe.

```
x = [(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)]
x_filtered = [(1,2),(3,4)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(x, schema=['src','trgt'])
df_1 = spark.createDataFrame(x_filtered, schema=['src', 'trgt'])
PROBLEM_DF = df.alias("df").join(df_1.alias("df_1"), ["src", "trgt"], 'right').select("df.*")
```

The occuring problem is now, that I'm not able to reference the columns anymore, without using the Alias:

```
PROBLEM_DF.src
PROBLEM_DF['df.src']  # <-- stil as df.src known
```

I thought that maybe the solution would be in toDF, to create a new Dataframe and hopefully loose the Alias in the process. However, that does not work:

```
PROBLEM_DF.toDF(*PROBLEM_DF.columns).src
```

So I ended up simply creating a new DF from scratch:

```
spark.createDataFrame(PROBLEM_DF.collect()).src
```

Although it works, I find it hard to believe that this is the simplest function or that this actually is the way to do it.
Is there actually a simpler approach? Something like "unalias" after the select has been done, to get rid of it and be ableto simply reference the column again by using its name.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey, it's working fine in Spark version `3.5.0`